# Characterizing the real numbers as a dense complete monoidal poset

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders, monoid

Let $P$ be a poset with a monoidal structure respecting the poset structure. This means there is an operation $P \times P \to P$ such that $a \leq b \implies ac \leq bc$.

As usual, call a poset complete if $P$ admits limits and colimits (in the sense of category theory). This means that one can always find an inf and a sup to any subset of $P$. (In other words, $P$ is a complete lattice.) Call $P$ *dense* if for any two $a <b$, there exist $c$ so that $ a <c< b$.

> What is the initial dense, complete, monoidal poset containing a copy of the integers? Must it be the real numbers adjoin $\pm \infty$?

> More generally, is there an adjunction between the category of monoidal posets, and the category of monoidal dense complete posets?

Comment: The poset of real numbers is not complete. Do you want to adjoin $\pm \infty$? In your definition of "fine", you mean probably $<$ instead of $\leq$? This is called density.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I've fixed the post.

Comment: I wonder why you don't want to include $+$ into your structure?

Comment: Being unfamiliar with the categorical notion of limits and colimits; what would be the difference between this and completeness in the topological sense or some other sense which has a natural interpretation in partial orders?

Comment: Martin: I also have in mind the example of non-negative integers, whose completion I would want to be $\mathbb R_{\geq 0}$. Asaf, you're right; limits and colimits are unnecessary language here. It just means that for any collection $Q \subset P$, there are elements $q_-, q_+ \in P$ such that $a \leq Q \implies a \leq q_-, a \geq Q \implies a \geq q_+$. (Here, $a \leq Q$ means $a \leq q$ for all $q \in Q$.) Moreover, $q_-$ has to satisfy the property that for any other $q_-'$, $q_-' \leq q_-$. Likewise for $q_+$.

Comment: I see, good. It should perhaps be noted that the property in the last sentence essentially says that $q_-$ and $q_+$ are unique (because of antisymmetry). So in other, much simpler words, $P$ is a complete lattice.

Comment: Yes, $P$ should be a complete lattice. Thanks, Asaf. I didn't know those words before :-).